# Show that, given an element $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, there is an integer $n \ge 1$ such that $n\bar{x} = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers. >Show that, given an element $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, there is an integer $n \ge 1$ such that $n\bar{x} = 0$.

I know that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = \left \{  \frac{a}{b} + \mathbb{Z} \mid a,b \in Z, b \neq 0 \right \}$. From that, $ \bar{x} =  \frac{a}{b} + c$ where $a,b, c \in Z$ and $ b \neq 0 $, so $n\left (  \frac{a}{b} + c \right ) = 0$. But when I try to solve $n\left (  \frac{a}{b} + c \right ) = 0$ the result is always $n=0$. Any help in solving this is welcome.

Comment: Notice that $k + \mathbb Z = 0 + \mathbb Z$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of $\overline x$ isn't quite right - the coset is actually

$$\frac a b + \mathbb{Z}$$

for some integers $a, b$. Now a coset $\alpha + \mathbb{Z}$ is zero in the quotient if and only if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$, so what you actually need is an $n$ so that

$$n \cdot \frac a b \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Can you think of such an $n$?

Comment: if $n=b$ then $n \cdot \frac a b $ is in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Bingo. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I think that if we play Bingo on $\Bbb Z^2$ it will take you longer than one comment to reach Bingo.